# DOMINO REST API get Collection sort column

Tags: rest, collections, lotus-domino, get-request

Hi I'm trying to get a sorted Collection from the Domino Rest Api. My database name is "Test/JSON_Views.nsf" and my views name "List".

The endpoint I use is
**/Test/JSON_Views.nsf/api/data/collections/name/List?sortcolumn=title&sortorder=ascending&count=20

But the JSON-Response entries aren't sorting by title in ascending order.

Should I make any settings to the column properties in the designer? If I set descending there for the title-column it works. But I want to change the sorting in my external java-application.

Is my endpoint correct? I use this [Domino API Docu](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Domino%20Access%20Services%209.0.1#action=openDocument&res_title=Viewfolder_entries_GET_dds10&content=apicontent) as Reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an additional sorting to your title column:

[image]

This gives the API the possibility to sort by title in both directions. You can do this with other columns too so you are very flexible in sorting this way.

Answer (score 1):

The doc says that if the column isn't sorted in design then the sortcolumn parameter has no effect, so the answer is "Yes" you should change the design of the desired column.  If doing that is unworkable in whatever context you use it, then create a second view and use that instead.

Comment: that's not the whole truth. Since the docu says " sortorder-Specifies the sort order. The parameter value should be either ascending or descending. Pair this parameter with sortcolumn." And that's what I'm trying to do. But it doesn't work at the moment.